# Unable to Locate Package python-pandas

Tags: apt, python

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. To install the Python pandas library, I ran

```
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```

The output was as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pandas
```

Why can the package not be located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable **universe repository** by executing:

`sudo add-apt-repository universe`

`sudo apt-get update`

Or by using the Software & Updates application:

[image: Imgur]

Then execute:

`sudo apt-get install python-pandas`

You may use Ubuntu Software Center instead:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository universe`? Great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Ubuntu 16.04, the python3 package version is available with the name `python3-pandas`.

You can use `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas` to install it.

Reference: [python3-pandas in packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3-pandas&searchon=names)

Comment: There aren't many python- prefixed packages left in Ubuntu 20.04 including the old python-pandas package. Most python- prefixed packages have been updated from python to python3 in 20.04.