# can not install libpq-dev in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dependencies, postgresql, database

I can not install libpq-dev for postgresql, i tried

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

and output

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 9.3.9-0ubuntu0.14.04) but 9.4.4-1.pgdg14.04+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/672338/unable-to-locate-package-python-pandas/672344#672344) enable all as shown in that image!

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`?

Answer (score 30):

Problem is solved!

I solved this with remove `libpq5` :

```
sudo apt-get remove libpq5
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: So simple! FYI - I had to `sudo apt-get update` first because I didn't have the latest sources (running on DigitalOcean's Ubuntu 14.04 image, which is probably a bit old)

Comment: I have run the commands (including apt-get update), but I still got a problem. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: This fix no longer works (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Not really a solution, as removing libpq5 requires removing everything that depends on it, which includes Postgres and everything that uses Postgres. I'm not deleting every single database on my system just to fix an Ubuntu packaging bug...

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, I had to add postgresql's repo:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get remove libpq5
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: Thank you so much you made by day :)

Comment: Removing libpq5 removes Postgres...

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved via following steps :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove libpq5
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```